# C# mod gives wrong answer not as python mod (%)

Tags: python, c#, modulo

I'm trying to get % result of ( -1%26 )
the result should be 25
in python it's right
but C# gives -1 as result
why and how to get 25 in C# not -1

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different kind of modulus function, like this:

```cs
int Modulus(int a, int b) { 
  return ((a % b) + b) % b; 
}
Console.WriteLine(Modulus(-1, 26)); // prints 25
```